# Issue Brownie setup, not sure if ganache installed properly - chainlink hackathon

Tags: python, hadoop-yarn, chainlink, ganache, brownie

I am new to this space and having an issue getting brownie to run my first deploy script. I am learning through the Chainlink Hackathon and following the brownie tutorial by Patrick Collins. I think the problem is with ganache. Any help would be appreciated.

When I ask for the version of ganache - it says not found (see below). when I try to install via npm, I receive  error no 13. Is this related to Mac OS?

Error message when trying to deploy script:

`brownie run scripts/deploy.py`

```
>Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

(base) x:brownie-hack mariposa$ brownie run scripts/deploy.py
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieHackProject is the active project.
  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/run.py", line 45, in main
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "brownie/network/main.py", line 50, in connect
    rpc.launch(active["cmd"], **active["cmd_settings"])
  File "brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 75, in launch
    self.process = self.backend.launch(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "brownie/network/rpc/ganache.py", line 69, in launch
    ganache_version = get_ganache_version(cmd_list[0])
  File "brownie/network/rpc/ganache.py", line 110, in get_ganache_version
    ganache_version_proc = psutil.Popen([ganache_executable, "--version"], stdout=PIPE)
  File "psutil/__init__.py", line 1319, in __init__
    self.__subproc = subprocess.Popen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ganache-cli': 'ganache-cli'
```

Dependencies /versions installed:

`$ node -v`

> v16.14.2

`$ npm -v`

> 8.5.0

`$ yarn -v`

> 3.2.0

`$ python --version`

> Python 2.7.10

`$ brownie`

> Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

`ganache-cli --version`

> bash: ganache-cli: command not found

`npm install -g ganache-cli`

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mariposa/.npm/_logs/2022-04-29T18_59_01_563Z-debug-0.log
(base) x:brownie-hack mariposa$ npm install ganache-cli@latest -g
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mariposa/.npm/_logs/2022-04-29T19_24_54_189Z-debug-0.log
(base) x:brownie-hack mariposa$ ganache-cli --version
```

`$brownie --network ganache-cli`

```
> Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum

> Usage:  brownie <command> [<args>...] [options <args>]...
```

This is the deploy script provided by chainlink hackathon. Error message in visual studio code that highlights brownie ("Import "brownie" could not be resolved pylance...")

```
from brownie import SimpleStorage, accounts

def main():
    account = accounts[0]
    simple_storage_contract = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})
    print(simple_storage_contract.number())
```

Comment: Welcome, can you pls run ``ganache-cli --version``and report the version? If that does not work you may need to install ganache-cli first by running ``npm install -g ganache-cli``

Comment: @RndmSymbl thank you. Both of these commands do not seem to be working (posted above) - looks like some kind permission issue possibly related to Mac OS?

Comment: Great. Yes you may not have permissions. You can try it without the ``-g`` flag and install it for your user only. Try just ''npm install ganache-cli``. alternatively, if you have the administrator password you can try with the ``-g`` flag and run ``su npm -g install ganache-cli``

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't actually to do with Ganache (the fact that Ganache gets stuck there is supposed to happen; that means it is running at that IP address and port).

What is happening is you have a syntax error in your `deploy.py` file at line 8. It is saying you have `simple.storage` when what you want is `simple_storage` (with the underscore instead of the period). Make sure you fix line 8 in the script **and save the file**.

Comment: Thank you. I think that was a previous version that was not saved. I am still having the ganache-cli error. I receive messages when searching for help functions:
`bash: ganache-cli: command not found`  when deploying the script: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ganache-cli': 'ganache-cli`
(base)

Comment: I have updated post with the new error message. part of it is resolved but I think the ganache issue persists.  thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Write terminal

```
sudo strong textnpm install -g ganache-cli
```